# Python , Matplotlib problem with font_manager font

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a personal style (using different classes inherit from a generic base class)
recently after an upgrade python gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/sys06.py", line 130, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/sys06.py", line 95, in main
    fig,axs = PalatinoItalic()(1,1,(12.0,4.0))#
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/qualityPlot/qualityplot.py", line 547, in __init__
    super().__init__(**self.parameters )
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/qualityPlot/qualityplot.py", line 124, in __init__
    super().__init__(**self.parameters )
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/qualityPlot/qualityplot.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(**self.parameters)
  File "/media/data/Programming/Python/ODEPyPackage/qualityPlot/basequalityplot.py", line 30, in __init__
    font_manager.fontManager.addfont(font_file)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1092, in addfont
    font = ft2font.FT2Font(path)
RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Can not load face.  Unknown file format.
```

this is the base class:

```
class BasePlot(metaclass=ABCMeta):

     @abstractmethod
     def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.parameters = kwargs
        self.nrows = None
        self.ncols = None
        self.figsize = None
  
        font_dirs  = ['/home/marco/.fonts', ]
        font_files = font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=font_dirs)       font_list 
        font_list  = font_manager.createFontList(font_files)
        font_manager.fontManager.ttflist.extend(font_list)
```

may somebody help me?

Comment: What is the format/extension of your font file?

Comment: ttf ... on the MacBook the things using some files works ... but not on gentoo linux I don't know why ... (both python3.9)